# Unable to install ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

I'm trying to install ionic on Windows but for some reason, I'm unable to. When I run the "npm install" everything looks fine, no errors, nothing weird happens, however when I try to run "ionic start" (or any ionic command, even just ionic -version) the shell says that "ionic is not recognized as an internal or external command".

I've tried everything but obviously, I'm still doing something wrong something. I tried uninstalling/re-installing/updating everything I could so I'm pretty sure that Nodejs and npm are fine.

From what I read online I found that this kind of error happens when the environmental variables are messed up, however, I don't exactly know what I'm supposed to change there. I've followed many guides and tutorials: some of them said that the PATH to npm should be under 'Roaming', others said that the PATH should be under 'Local', some said that it should be in 'Program Files' and others said that what matters is the order in which you write the PATH variables.

Some just said to reinstall node and after that everything should be fine but none of these suggestions worked.

Can anyone help me? What kind of environmental variables do I need to put in for this to work?

Should I remove the node and start from scratch? If so, where should I install node so that I don't have weird path problems later on?

If you need any additional information on the problem please say so. Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Can I assume you installed using `-g` flag to install it globally? Like `npm install -g ionic cordova`?

Comment: Yes, I did it exactly like that

Comment: Can you try to execute this command on the `cmd`? `%appdata%\npm\ionic -v`

Comment: When I execute the command is shows the full path to 'npm\ionic' and then says the same thing "ionic is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: So it seems that it is not installed on the default `npm` folder. There's this command that shows you the root global npm folder, you can run `npm root -g` to check where npm is installing your packages and add that path to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: It says it's under AppData\Local\node_modules.

I have no idea why. So I just need to add this as a new line inside the PATH variable?

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `npm` packages are not being installed on the default npm folder (`%appdata%\npm`). There's this command that shows you the root global npm folder, you can run [`npm root -g`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/root) to check where npm is installing the packages and add that path to your `PATH` environment variable.

First, run the command bellow:

```
C:\> npm root -g
```

It will give you a path like this:

```
C:\my\actual\path\node_modules
```

Grab the path without `node_modules` (`C:\my\actual\path\`), and then add it to your `PATH` environment variable.

> **Warning:** don't forget to remove the `node_modules` from the path it gave you.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have changed anything. 

Just to be sure, do I need to add this under the "System variables" only? Or do I also need to add it under the "User variables" tab too?

Also, could the path to nodejs have anything to do with this problem?

Comment: Mine is registered under user variables but it shouldn't be an issue. Also, the path to node shouldn't be an issue as long as it's visible (declared on PATH). Are you able to navigate to the path you found from `npm root -g` and check if ionic and cordova files are there?

Comment: @DarioFerretti I forgot to add an observation, did you removed the `node_modules` from the path?

Comment: In the path I found from "npm root" there are 3 folders called ionic, cordova and npm. I didn't remove node_modules from the path, so that might be the reason. I'll try now

Comment: Ok it seems I did everything right this time. Ionic is now working properly and I was able to start a template project. I don't know if I'll encounter more problems like this but now at least I know how to fix them. Thank you for your help, you are a life saver!

Answer (score -1):

Once you set your PATH variable, you need to restart your computer.

Comment: Yes, I restarted after each change of the PATH variable but it never worked. I'm probably just writing the wrong stuff in the PATH variables